# identifying the distribution and finding expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose there are n boxes labelled $1, 2,\ldots, n$ and $n$ balls labelled
$1, 2,\ldots,n$. Balls are placed at random in the boxes. Let $X$ be the
number of empty boxes. Find $E(X)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

I am taking $X_i= 1$ if box is empty and 0 otherwise.
so $\sum Xi$ is the total number of empty boxes which follows $Binomial(n,P(X_i=1))$.
Now I am taking $P(X_i=1)= \frac {(n-1)^n} {n^n}$.
Is it correct?

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Comment: I was thinking something  along the lines of defining an indicator function.I will edit the question to include that.

Comment: I guess this is where the downvote came from (not me!). People here like when OPs show their work

Comment: So far your method looks good to me.